# Query All Roads with Overpass API and export as polygon

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have a query for Overpass API.

```
   mybbox = '8.9281,48.4379,9.1794,48.5827'
    overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"
    overpass_query = """
    [out:json];
    // gather results
    (
      // query part for: "highway=*"
      node["highway"]("""+mybbox+""");
      way["highway"]("""+mybbox+""");
      relation["highway"]("""+mybbox+""");
    );
    // print results
    out center;
    >;
    out skel qt;
    """
```

I save result to a .json file. And the type is way. 
But I want to define a road width and export road data as polygon. 
For example if highway ==  motorway the road must be a polygon type and its width must be 4 meters. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Not with Overpass API. You have to define the road polygon yourself.

Comment: Dou you have any example @scai?

Comment: Unfortunately not. However a helpful hint: You can look at the `width` tag of the way. Since most highways don't have a width set you can alternatively use the `lanes` tag. If none of them are present the road has very likely only one lane for each direction or only a single lane at all if it is a `oneway` road.

Answer (score 3):

As the others say, it is not possible to get the road width via Overpass API; you have to calculate it yourself. The API only serves to look up various objects of interest and to download them. You may filter the results using a tag, e.g. `[width]` or similar: there are alternatives like `est_width` or `width_street`. To find out how frequently each tag is used and which variant fits your needs, see [this page](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys) with stats on usage (use the search box on right).